# How do I pass Date to Java using Postman?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, postman

I'm using postman to test the backend, right now if I don't include the date parameter, using postman would be like(via form-data):

`Key: "events" value: {"locations":"bc"}
Key: "File" value: (select a file)`

But if I include {"locations":"bc", "eventsTime": "2015-09-09 09:09:09"} in postman, this will not work since I pass the date parameter as a String instead of LocalDataTime in Java. So my question is how do I pass this as a LocalDateTime variable in postman?
Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Thanks for all your answers! It seems like the best way is to parse the String to date object in the java controller file. Then pass the date as String in postman.

Comment: The HTTP protocol transmit strings. You have to parse the string in your java code.

Comment: Postman will always pass the date as a string. It's up to your server to parse the string into a `LocalDateTime` object

Comment: If what you're sending is JSON, and if you have configured Spring to use Jackson to deserialize the JSON, then what is expected is the ISO format of the LocalDateTime (i.e. the one that is used when calling toString() on the LocalDateTime: `2015-09-09T09:09:09`.

Answer (score -1):

Use java.text.SimpleDateFormat and java.util.Date to parse the string.

Comment: Hello, and welcome on StackOverflow! Thanks for taking the time to answer a question :) Recommending a library to use is nice, but you may want to explain more why he has to parse the date in his code, so he understands the approach he should take.